# knockout.js - ReferenceError on data bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Beginning with bnockout.js, I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Maybe someone there could help a bit :-)

```
<!-- ko foreach: quotes -->
<tr>
    <td><p data-bind="text: quoteAuthor.name"></p></td>
    <td><p data-bind="text: quoteText"></p></td>
    <td data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(quoteReferences)"></td>
    <td style="width: 1px;">
    <div data-bind="if: quoteReferences">
    <!-- ko foreach: quoteReferences -->
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: quoteReference.url }" target="_blank">see <span data-bind="text: $index"></span></a>&nbsp;
    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 1px;">
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeQuote" class="btn btn-danger">Remove Quote</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr data-bind="if: quoteEvent">
    <td><p><b>Event</b></p></td>
    <td><p data-bind="text: quoteEvent.name"></p> - <p data-bind="text: quoteEvent.country.name"></p></td>
    <td><p data-bind="text: quoteEvent.date"></p></td>
    <td style="width: 1px;"></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This the debug toJSON trace:

```
[{"id":0,"url":"http://www.google.fr","validators":null,"createdBy":null,"createdDate":null,"version":0}]
```

The error is on the "if:quoteReferences" tag, but the "foreach:quotes" works fine. And there is no error when quoteReferences is "Array[0]". And the "if:quoteEvent" tag is ok for null or non null values.

To me, I have to say, the first issue comes from the fact that ajax function is returning a data structure where arrays are interpreted as Array objects. This why I had to make this loop to interpret the result:

```
var uri = '/quotes?search=' + self.textPattern();
ajax(uri, 'GET').done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (index in data.content) {
        var item = data.content[index]; //DEBUG arrays turned into objects...
        console.log(item);
        self.quotes.push(item);
    }
})
```

This is how the data structure looks like:

[image]

UPDATE: I've made a deep observable refactoring on the data wo more success. quoteReferences won't be exploited :-(

```
function deepObservable(object) {
    // console.log(object);
    if (object instanceof Array) {
        var tmp = ko.observableArray();
        for (index in object) {
            tmp.push(deepObservable(object[index]));
        }
        return tmp;
    } else if (object instanceof Object) {
        for (property in object) {
            object[property] = deepObservable(object[property]);
        }
        return object;
    }
    return ko.observable(object);
}
```

Comment: Whats the exact error? `quoteReferences` being undefined? Have you tried with `quoteReferences.length>0` condition.

Comment: knockout-3.4.1.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return quoteReferences }"(…)

Comment: I tried quoteReferences.length comparison, putting parenthesis or not...

Comment: The fact is, I guess, that quoteReferences is not an array, as I said in the question. But why does it kill the data binding then? Isn't not null valid as a condition?

Comment: Null and empty array are fine for `quoteReferences`. The error is when you dont have `quoteReferences` property defined on your quote object i.e. it does not exist. Try logging to console the `quotes` array after you get data.

Comment: Thx Dandy. When logged, my data structures seem fine, except for the object conversion of the arrays. My track know is about changing every Array to an ko.observableArray an I was wondering if you'd know about any smart kind of "deep observableArray" API to use, instead of the DIY approach? Taking any advise :-)

Comment: `data-bind="attr: { href: quoteReference.url }"` should probably be `data-bind="attr: { href: quoteReference }"`. You don't seem to declare `quoteReference` (singular) anywhere. If you meant to refer to each item in `quoteReferences` array, you're already in its scope.

Comment: I've read the question multiple times now and I still have no idea what the problem is. This question sorely misses an error description and enough actual code and data (not screenshots of data) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @haim770 yes you're right : I mixed up the context with parameter passed to the functions anyway... should have wrote data-bind="attr: { href: url }"

Comment: @ThomasEscolan, Obviously, I meant `data-bind="attr: { href: url }"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @haim770 intuited it, the whole problem (after having figured out the object/array question) came from the contextual syntax inside the second loop. Thank you so much JavaScript for ending up into errors so out of the subject... By the way, this ultimate code works (see REST client in question):

```
<!-- ko foreach: quotes -->
<tr>
    <td><p data-bind="text: quoteAuthor.name"></p></td>
    <td>
        <div data-bind="visible: likesCount"><span data-bind="text: likesCount"></span></div>
        <a data-bind="click: $parent.likeQuote" title="click to like it"><span data-bind="visible: !quoteLiked" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" style="color:red"></span></a>
        <a data-bind="click: $parent.likeQuote" title="click to unlike it"><span data-bind="visible: quoteLiked" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="color:red"></span></a>
    </td>
    <td><p data-bind="text: quoteText"></p></td>
    <td style="width: 1px;">
    <!-- ko foreach: quoteReferences -->
        &nbsp;<a data-bind="attr: { href: url }" target="_blank">see #<span data-bind="text: 1 + $index()"></span></a>
        <div data-bind="visible: starsCount"><span data-bind="text: starsCount"></span></div>
        <a data-bind="click: $root.starRef" title="click to star it"><span data-bind="visible: !refStarred" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="color:gold"></span></a>
        <a data-bind="click: $root.starRef" title="click to unstar it"><span data-bind="visible: refStarred" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:gold"></span></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.beginAddRef" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">New Reference</button>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 1px;">
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeQuote" class="btn btn-danger">Remove Quote</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="if: quoteEvent">
        <td><p><b>Event</b></p></td>
        <td colspan="2"><p data-bind="text: quoteEvent.name"></p> - <p data-bind="text: quoteEvent.country.name"></p></td>
        <td><p data-bind="text: quoteEvent.date"></p></td>
        <td style="width: 1px;"></td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Thank you everyone for having teased me along ;-)